# Spotfire - How to make a division if the custom expression contains Then keyword with over formula in a crosstab

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to achieve a calculation in Spotfire. Where I am trying below expression but it is throwing an error.

```
Sum([Exp Increase]) / Sum([History]) * Sum([Prices]) THEN Sum([Value]) OVER (LastPeriods(4,[Axis.Columns])) / Sum([Prices]) OVER (LastPeriods(4,[Axis.Columns]))
```

I think it's because I am trying to make a division to an expression which contains "Then" keyword with Over expression.

Can someone help here? I have also attached Spotfire working file.

Thanks,
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

The reason your expression doesn't work is because you can't have more than 1 OVER statement in 1 expression.

I was having a similar issue a couple weeks back...my solution wasn't pretty but here you go:

1)Store the result of the first half of the expression (i.e. `Sum([Exp Increase]) / Sum([History]) * Sum([Prices]) THEN Sum([Value]) OVER (LastPeriods(4,[Axis.Columns]))`) into a calculated column (lets call it firstHalf)

2)Repeat w/ the second half (`Sum([Prices]) OVER (LastPeriods(4,[Axis.Columns]))`). Lets call it secondHalf.

3)Here's where it gets tricky. I was using my calculated columns in KPI's so it automatically did the periods for me. So I could just use `Avg(firstHalf)/Avg(secondHalf)` and be done. But if you're not then you can try doing something like `Avg(firstHalf)/Avg(secondHalf) OVER (LastPeriods(4,[Axis.Columns]))` and see if that works.

The reason Avg(...) works is because your calculated columns looks something like this:

```
| Period   | firstHalf             |
|----------+-----------------------|
| 1        | 120                   |
|----------+-----------------------|
| 1        | 120                   |
|----------+-----------------------|
| 1        | 120                   |
|----------+-----------------------|
| 1        | 120                   |
|----------+-----------------------|
| 2        | 300                   |
|----------+-----------------------|
| 2        | 300                   |
------------------------------------
```

etc

So taking Avg() of a specific month will just return the value for that month.